# Not receiving hours agreed on in acceptance letter

Tags: job-offer

I was hired for a job and my acceptance letter stated it would be for 40 hours, however my supervisor has cut hours to 32 without any kind of notice. So I wanted to know is this practice legal??

Comment: In what country?

Comment: The answer to your question depends on the laws of the country you are working in. Whether your employer is in violation of the terms of your employment contract depends upon the terms of your employment contract. If you don't have an employment contract, then the applicable default is the laws of your country. I assume that the terms of your employment contract must be in compliance with the laws of your country.

Comment: It's all in your contract. Verbal agreements are binding only in certain countries, but you haven't told us where you're from.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where you are so I'll keep this as generic as possible.  You need to check your contract too see if it specifies a certain number of hours.

In some places (for example the UK) there has been a lot in the press about "zero hour" contracts, these are jobs (and a lot of employers seem to be doing it) with no GUARANTEED hours, so the employer can vary as suits.  If you are on a zero hours contract it can be cut just like you said.  If it specifies hours, talk to your manager, and if necessary a lawyer.

If you only have the letter, check what it says, if it says you normally work 40 hours, that isn't the same as saying your minimum would be 40 hours, so if necessary get some qualified advice.